# Are there nice walking/hiking trails around Shibu Onsen in November?

Tags: japan

I'll be traveling to Shibu Onsen in November and wondering if it's worth spending an extra day to explore the area and get out into Nature, maybe see some Autumn/early Winter foliage. I can't seem to find anything about any walking trails – people seem to either come for this area just for the hot springs and the snowmonkeys, or the skiing in Shiga Kogen once the snow season starts. I also read that the chairlifts in Shiga may not operate before the ski season so it may even be difficult to explore that area.

Comment: I guess this question will fit the site better if you leave out the 'nice' but include 'available' walking trails, as nice depends on opinion. And asking for how to find the information. Please also include how well you read and possibly speak Japanse.

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid November may be a little late.  The Shiga Kogen official tourism site (which covers Shibu Onsen) lists a [number of hiking trails](https://shigakogen.co.jp/activity/) nearby, most notably the [Ikemeguri (Pond Loop) Course](https://shigakogen.co.jp/activity/pond/), but the referenced [Maeyama summer chair lift stops running for the season on October 29th](https://shigakogen.co.jp/hours-price/#summer_lift).  This doesn't mean you *can't* hike, but it does strongly imply that there will be zero facilities or public transport available and weather conditions are unlikely to be in your favor.

Note: All links above are in Japanese.  [Go Nagano](https://www.go-nagano.net/en/theme/id=19501) has English summaries, but in far less detail.

Comment: Just letting you know that all your Japanese links point to a 404 not found page.